# Symbology/points not showing on ArcGIS Online web map but data is present

Tags: symbology, arcgis-online

I have a layer that has been symbolized in an ArcDesktop project.  The project was saved and Shared As --> Publish Service up to our ArcGIS Online account.  All layers and their symbology have uploaded flawlessly up to this point.  However, this particular layer does not.  The data is there and if you know where one of the points is located and click on it, a pop up window with the correct data appears.  The symbology shows up in the Content bar on the left of the web map interface just fine.

My first attempt was to upload the project with all layers.  The first 4 layers showed symbology correctly but the remaining 11 layers that all have the same symbology (which is different from the first 4 layers) are the ones not showing.  (link to web map: http://arcg.is/1S5iWtg)

Several attempts after that were to upload in various ways that would keep the symbology.  Including, uploading smaller groups, uploading individual layers at a time, smaller number of natural breaks (from 7 to 4), using more simplistic symbols, none of which worked.  While in ArcGIS Online, if I try to change the symbols, as soon as I click on the Change Style icon, all the points then appear as small black dots (which was not the specified symbology).

Here is the example of the web map with just one of the layers uploaded that are not showing up.  (link to web map: http://arcg.is/1S5ltDE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks the the schema on the service changed. The field that should be driving the renderer is not present on the service.

"field":"50th" is what you see under the renderer info on the service but the closest thing to that field on the service is "F50th" which is the field name and alias.

Comment: Yep, this was basically the problem.  I was in a rush and was not thinking about the fact that I was uploading a shapefile with field names that start with a number which always seem to cause a problem somewhere.  I changed the field names, re-uploaded and the symbols appeared how they should have.  For learning purposes, when you say "under the renderer info" do you mean the ArcGIS REST service Directory page under Drawing info?

Comment: Yup, I meant drawinginfo sorry about that. So at the service level you would look under drawingInfo": {
"renderer": {

Comment: No problem.  Thanks for the knowledge sharing!  Know I know where to look in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Symbols can also not show up if the symbology was based on a 'domained' field and one or more domain values have changed